# Selecting precise data through Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have a list of college basketball teams in my database. The names match exactly as they're found on this site I'm trying to parse. The website is a big table. I want to select/match specific cells based on those teams in my database. I don't have a preference if it's css or xpath selection method. Whatever works. Here is a small sample of the return (added some linebreaks for visual purposes):

```sh
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://kenpom.com/"))
=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39c14e4 name="tbody" 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd7f39c1174 "\n">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39c0fd0 name="tr" 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39c0cd8 name="td" 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd7f39c0a6c "1">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39c0800 name="td" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd7f39c0774 name="style" value="text-align:left;">] 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39c0224 name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd7f39c01c0 name="href" value="team.php?team=Kentucky">] 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd7f39bdc40 "Kentucky">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd7f39bda38 " ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39bd984 name="span" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd7f39bd90c name="class" value="seed">] 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd7f39bd3d0 "1">]>]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39bd100 name="td" 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39bcebc name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd7f39bce58 name="href" value="conf.php?c=SEC">] 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd7f39bc994 "SEC">]>]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39bc69c name="td" 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd7f39bc480 "38-1">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39bc2b4 name="td" 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd7f39bc070 ".9757">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39b9d34 name="td" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd7f39b9cd0 name="class" value="divide">] 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd7f39b967c "119.3">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39b93d4 name="td" 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39b9140 name="span" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd7f39b90b4 name="class" value="seed">] 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd7f39b8a10 "5">]>]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39b86dc name="td" 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd7f39b82a4 "86.5">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39b5fcc name="td" 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39b5db0 name="span" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd7f39b5d24 name="class" value="seed">] 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd7f39b57e8 "2">]>]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39b54b4 name="td" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd7f39b5450 name="class" value="divide">] 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd7f39b4e38 "63.5">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39b4ab4 name="td" 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39b4820 name="span" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd7f39b47bc name="class" value="seed">] 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd7f39b4258 "251">]>]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39b1ef4 name="td" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd7f39b1e54 name="class" value="divide">] 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd7f39b1904 "+.048">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39b1710 name="td" 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39b1314 name="span" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd7f39b1288 name="class" value="seed">] 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd7f39b0cfc "69">]>]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39b0810 name="td" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd7f39b0798 name="class" value="divide">] 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd7f39add68 ".6829">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39adb88 name="td" 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39ad980 name="span" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd7f39ad91c name="class" value="seed">] 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd7f39ad430 "31">]>]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39ad0ac name="td" 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd7f39ace90 "106.0">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39acc9c name="td" 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39aca94 name="span" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd7f39aca1c name="class" value="seed">] 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd7f39ac5a8 "31">]>]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39ac2b0 name="td" 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd7f39ac0a8 "99.2">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39a9ed4 name="td" 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39a9c90 name="span" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd7f39a9bc8 name="class" value="seed">] 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd7f39a96f0 "29">]>]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39a9394 name="td" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd7f39a9308 name="class" value="divide">] 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd7f39a8c78 ".5560">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39a8a5c name="td" 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f39a8714 name="span" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd7f39a864c name="class" value="seed">] 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd7f39a8084 "100">]>]>]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd7f3c61cd0 "\n">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f3c61b90 name="tr" 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7f3c61960 name="td" 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd7f3c61708 "2">]>,
```

I have a team.name of "Kentucky" in my database, so I want to target the rank of Kentucky. How would I do that?

Rank: 1 is found at  `//*[@id="ratings-table"]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]`

Team: Kentucky is found at `//*[@id="ratings-table"]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[2]`

How do I target/find the "Rank" by searching/using "Kentucky"? I'm interested in a few other columns but just this one example should explain the rest.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking for help debugging code, we expect sample input, which in your case would be the minimum HTML necessary to work with your code. We expect the minimal code to demonstrate your question. You're displaying an `inspect` output which slows our ability to help you. Please review other questions related to Nokogiri to get an idea of how to ask and what you should supply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one possible XPath :

```
//*[@id="ratings-table"]/tbody/tr[contains(td[2],"Kentucky")]/td[1]
```

The XPath looks for `tr` element having `td[2]` child *contains* word `"Kentucky"`, and then return the corresponding `td[1]` child.

Alternatively, you can check for *exact* value of `a` child of the `td[2]` to find the target row, and then return the target column (`td`) element :

```
//*[@id="ratings-table"]/tbody/tr[td[2]/a = "Kentucky"]/td[1]
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to be more exact than contains? e.g. If I search for contains "Michigan" I want to make sure it gets Michigan and not Michigan State...

Comment: Thanks! Additionally, do you know anything about ruby/ror? I tried `data.xpath("//*[@id="ratings-table"]/tbody/tr[td[2]/a = "Kentucky"]/td[1]")` and got syntax errors:

```
`SyntaxError: (irb):54: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'`
                            ^
`(irb):54: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or `
`(irb):54: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting end-of-input`

Comment: I don't know ruby, but that's a common problem across programming languages: **conflicting string delimiter**. Replace double quotes with single quotes in your XPath expression : `doc.xpath("//*[@id='ratings-table']/tbody/tr[td[2]/a = 'Kentucky']/td[1]")`